# Python Reduce : Order of arguments cause error

Tags: python, mapreduce, reduce

I am trying to understand the process of Reduce in Python by running the following commands in Colab Notebook :

```
pList20 = ["Ram", "RamPM", "Shyam", "PMShyam", "Sita", "SiPMMta"]
print(pList20)
pList21A = list(map(lambda x : (x,len(x)),pList20) )    # returns a list of tuples
print(pList21A)
pList21B = list(map(lambda x : (len(x),x),pList20) )    # returns a list of tuples
print(pList21B)
print('----')
print(pList21A)
pVal22A = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]), pList21A)  #   adding and concatenating elements in a list
print(pVal22A)
print(pList21B)
pVal22B = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]), pList21B)  #   adding and concatenating elements in a list
print(pVal22B)
print('----')
#print(pList21A)
#pVal22C = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x[1]+y[1], x[0]+y[0]), pList21A)  #   adding and concatenating elements in a list
#print(pVal22C)
print(pList21B)
pVal22D = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x[1]+y[1], x[0]+y[0]), pList21B)  #   adding and concatenating elements in a list
print(pVal22D)
```

the first two reduce functions are going through as expected, but the last two are throwing an error. Output and error is shown below.

Cannot figure out what is going wrong

```
['Ram', 'RamPM', 'Shyam', 'PMShyam', 'Sita', 'SiPMMta']
[('Ram', 3), ('RamPM', 5), ('Shyam', 5), ('PMShyam', 7), ('Sita', 4), ('SiPMMta', 7)]
[(3, 'Ram'), (5, 'RamPM'), (5, 'Shyam'), (7, 'PMShyam'), (4, 'Sita'), (7, 'SiPMMta')]
----
[('Ram', 3), ('RamPM', 5), ('Shyam', 5), ('PMShyam', 7), ('Sita', 4), ('SiPMMta', 7)]
('RamRamPMShyamPMShyamSitaSiPMMta', 31)
[(3, 'Ram'), (5, 'RamPM'), (5, 'Shyam'), (7, 'PMShyam'), (4, 'Sita'), (7, 'SiPMMta')]
(31, 'RamRamPMShyamPMShyamSitaSiPMMta')
----
[(3, 'Ram'), (5, 'RamPM'), (5, 'Shyam'), (7, 'PMShyam'), (4, 'Sita'), (7, 'SiPMMta')]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-b1b1ac48507f> in <module>()
     17 #print(pVal22C)
     18 print(pList21B)
---> 19 pVal22D = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x[1]+y[1], x[0]+y[0]), pList21B)  #   adding and concatenating elements in a list
     20 print(pVal22D)

<ipython-input-41-b1b1ac48507f> in <lambda>(x, y)
     17 #print(pVal22C)
     18 print(pList21B)
---> 19 pVal22D = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x[1]+y[1], x[0]+y[0]), pList21B)  #   adding and concatenating elements in a list
     20 print(pVal22D)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I am sorry if it is something very simple, but would be grateful if someone could explain why the +  operand is being supported in the first two reduce functions but are not supported in the second two reduce functions.

Comment: "Cannot figure out what is going wrong" - Nobody can unless you'll edit code sample in something readable..

Comment: i thought that the code is self explanatory! the data is there, the code is there, the output is there. in two cases, the code runs as expected, in the other two cases, the code throws and error ... error is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `lambda x,y: (x[1]+y[1], x[0]+y[0])` swaps the order of the components.

- First it processes the first two elements; `(3, 'Ram')` and `(5, 'RamPM')` → `('RamRamPM', 8)`.
- Then it tries to process the result with the third element; `('RamRamPM', 8)` and `(5, 'Shyam')` gives error, because it attempts to add `'RamRamPM' + 5` and `8 + 'Shyam'`

Comment: but the same two elements are being added -- correctly -- in the first two statements. the only difference is that in the position ( or order) of the output. that is my confusion

Comment: The reduce function works like `(a + b) + c` so the result of `(a + b)` is added to `c`. Here, the result of `(3, 'Ram') + (5, 'RamPM')` is `('RamRamPM', 8)` but that can't be added to the third element, `(5, 'Shyam')`.

Comment: Sorry, I've just noticed I had the wrong values in my answer; it's the *third* element that's being added to the first result.

Comment: Added a bit more explanation of what's happening into my answer; hopefully it's clearer now?

Comment: (3, 'Ram') + (5, 'RamPM') should be (8, 'RamRamPM'), why ('RamRamPM', 8) ?? and then (8, 'RamRamPM') can be added to (5, 'Shyam') ... i am still puzzled

Comment: The calculation is `(x[1] + y[1], x[0]+y[0])`; the first element of that is `x[1] + y[1]` which is `'Ram' + 'RamPM'` and the second element is `x[0] + y[0]` which is `3 + 5`. The lambda swaps the order of the two parts.